# What does Junior mean when he says "That was the brother."?

Tags: the-sopranos

In this conversation from *The Sopranos* S03E07, what does Junior's answer mean?

> Tony: And let me ask you something about this JFK worship of yours,
>     what about Hoffa and the teamsters?
>
> Junior: That was the brother.
>
> Tony: Oh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He was talking about JFK's brother Robert who, as Attorney General, went on a crusade against the mob. RFK was instrumental in getting Hoffa put away on a jury tampering charge. Many believe this activity led to JFK's assassination by a paid mafia operative, though no reliable evidence supports this.

[Wikipedia - Robert Kennedy and the Mafia »](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_F._Kennedy#Organized_crime_and_the_Teamsters)

Comment: I saw a video of an exchange between Hoffa and RFK and they really disliked each other. And this was not a very sophisticated conversation; IIRC RFK asks Hoffa if he was a little girl or something.

Comment: @releseabe -- Yeah. It really got heated.